# parse username from td tags into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, split, xmlhttprequest

If i have the `http.responseText` stored in a `javascript` variable e.g named `sourcecode` which contains the whole source code of the page from which i want to extract the updated username from, how do i do that?
The username is displayed in the following tag within the page's source code:

```
<td align="right" valign="center" width="100%"> Your name has been updated to Bob</td>
```

I want to be able to use something like split to get the username, in this case Bob from the source code of the page and set it as a variable named username.
So doing `alert(username)` will alert a box containing (in this case) `Bob`.
I don't want to use `jquery`.
The td tag is in:
http://pastebin.com/M4dUzLAa.

Comment: Convert the HTML to a jQuery object and use a selector to get the text of the relevant element, then split that by a space and grab the last item. Without seeing the returned HTML it's impossible for anyone to help you effectively.

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions, if your username(bob) is stored in another variable like $user in php, you could try to look for the string ^user$ and then parse it into html, just saying.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I mentioned in the last part i don't want to use jquery. Here is where it is:http://pastebin.com/M4dUzLAa.

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts here:

- Extract the td that contains the data, without jQuery. In modern browsers you have [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) so you can write something like `usernameTD = document.querySelectorAll("td[align=right]");` You may need to modify this CSS selector depending on your HTML. 
  If you can modify the HTML, add an id to the td containing the username so you can use [getElementByID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)
- Extract the username from the td text `name = usernameTD[0].nodeValue.replace("Your name has been updated to ", "");`

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal to parse a user name like this, but if you really have to do it this way, you can use the following code:

```
var pattern = /Your name has been updated to ([^\<]*)\</;
var match = pattern.exec(sourcecode);
if (match) {
    var userName = match[1];
    alert(userName);
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aHQ8P/

Note that this will only work with exactly the conditions that you describe. If the wording *Your name has been updated to ...* changes, or another string like that appears in the source code, then you will start having problems.